# Why Npm is installing different 40+ modules other other computer but few packages on one

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

I really dont know why the NPM has started downloading about 40+ modules on `Npm install` but my package.json only contains following dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^1.6.2",
        "vscode": "0.10.x"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "fs": "^0.0.2"
    }
```

Following are the list it started. Besides these modules there are about double of this number downloaded and added below but i didnt show here.

Is there any way to reset. I have tried to remove the modules folder and install again it started adding again.

[image]

**Yesterday when i run i only get these dependencies only on other PC.**

[image]

Comment: Your dependencies can have dependencies.

Comment: @HeadCode yes i know but yesterday when i run i only get those folders and now on other computer its getting alot of folders.

Comment: @HeadCode But shouldn't all the dependencies be nested?

Comment: @Seamus It depends on the version of npm. I think starting with version 3 the dependencies directory got a lot flatter. Also, I have no idea what npm looks like on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HeadCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156046/headcode) is correct. npm3 installs some dependencies in a flat way.

From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3):

> While npm2 installs all dependencies in a nested way, npm3 tries to mitigate the deep trees and redundancy that such nesting causes. npm3 attempts this by installing some secondary dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in a flat way, in the same directory as the primary dependency that requires it.

So, if you are using npm v2.x on one machine, and npm v3.x on another, you can get very different folder structures under your `node_modules` folder.

Comment: thank you the latest version is installing alot of folders in modules section compared to older version. it solved the problem when i updated the node js and NPM in all my working PC